# File not found when accessing public folder in react (file is there)

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have a react-vite app structured like so:

```
├── App.css
├── App.tsx
├── CardGame
│   ├── CardGame.tsx
│   └── GameChooser.tsx
├── DashboardOptions.tsx
├── Data
├── Types
├── UserAvatar.tsx
├── db
├── hooks
├── index.css
├── main.tsx
├── public
│   └── game_assets
│       ├── phoneme_audio
│       │   ├── -a-.mp3
│       │   ├── -ae-.mp3
│       │   ├── -air-.mp3
│       │   ├── -ar-.mp3
│       │   ├── -b-.mp3
│       │   ├── -ch-.mp3
│       │   ├── -d-.mp3
[...]
│       ├── readme.txt
├── ui
│   ├── AddStudentModal.tsx
│   └── Navbar.tsx
├── utils
│   ├── auth.ts
│   └── helpers.ts
└── vite-env.d.ts
```

I am trying to access the `phoneme_audio` assets when a sound is presented to the user. Here is the code (from `helpers.ts`)

```
 function getPhonemeAudio(phoneme: string) {
  const formattedPhoneme = phoneme.replace(/\//g, '-');
  const filePath = `/game_assets/phoneme_audio/${formattedPhoneme}.mp3`;
  const audio = new Audio(filePath);
  audio.play();
  console.log(`Playing phoneme: ${phoneme}`);
}
```

However this returns a file not found error every time. I'm not sure why - isn't this how you access `public` in react?

Answer (score 0):

You’re missing `/phoneme_audio/` in the path. Instead of this:

```
const filePath = `/game_assets/${formattedPhoneme}.mp3`;
```

Try this:

```
const filePath = `/game_assets/phoneme_audio/${formattedPhoneme}.mp3`;
```

Comment: Oh dear - no it doesn't work with that in there either. I had removed it while experimenting, my bad thanks for noticing!